# What's the difference between self and its variants in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm currently learning Rust and trying to gain a comprehensive understanding of self and its variants. While I understand the fundamental difference between `Self`, `self` and `&self`, I'm having difficulty understanding `*self`, `**self`, and `&mut self`.

1. How does `*self` differ from `Self`, `self`, and `&self`? What
   specific use cases does it cater to?
2. Similar to the first question, what is the role of `**self` in Rust? In what scenarios would it be more suitable than the other variants?
3. Lastly, `&mut self` seems to imply mutability, but how does it behave differently from self and `&self`?

For reference, I've looked into this Reddit post, but it doesn't provide a clear explanation of the differences between `*self`, `**self`, and `&mut self`.

I'd appreciate detailed explanations or resources where I can deepen my understanding. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the documentation", or "the source code"? Is your question about the difference between `*` and `&`?

Comment: The page you linked containes neither of `self`, `*self`, and `**self`, not `&self` or `&mut self`.

Comment: I cannot find **self and *self in the documentation. But it is easy to find the difference between self, &self, and &mut self here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-is-different-between-mut-self-and-mut-self/59708. Do you know the answer to my question to not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rust, [methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html) in `impl` blocks may (or may not) take a *receiver* parameter:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
    fn my_func(&self, other_parameter: SomeType) -> ReturnType {
        //     ^^^^^ this is the receiver
        // ...
    }
}
```

The receiver has the special name `self`, but is otherwise very much like a normal function parameter. By using a receiver called `self`, the function can be called like this: `my_value.my_func(arg)` as syntactic sugar for `MyStruct::my_func(my_value, arg)`. The most common types of receiver are:

- `fn my_func(self, ...etc` takes the type by value and takes ownership of it when called. That is, `self: MyStruct`.
- `fn my_func(&self, ...etc` takes the type by shared reference, does not take ownership. That is, `self: &MyStruct`
- `fn my_func(&mut self, ...etc` takes the type by mutable reference, does not take ownership. That is, `self: &mut MyStruct`.

There are other receiver types (e.g. `self: Box<Self>`), but they're less common and I trust you can look them up yourself.

So when you see `*self`, what it means is simply dereferencing the `self` variable defined in the function signature, just like you'd dereference any other variable. The *only* difference is the special name `self` and the fact that this means the type is often implicit in the receiver syntax. If the function takes `&self`, for example, then `*self` simply de-references it back to the non-referenced type of the structure the method is defined on.

---

PS. In future, when writing questions please give some example code *in your question* **and** if you're referring to external documentation *link to it*. This will make it much easier for people to understand what you mean and answer the correct question promptly. Your question as written is not very clear (as pointed out by commenters).