# How to fix the following move error caused by variable assignment?

Tags: rust

The following `Screen` struct has methods that handle the `Input` enum:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Input {
    Text(String),
    None,
    Exit,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum InputError {
    NotUTF8(Vec<u8>),
    EmptyString,
    IoError(std::io::Error),
}

struct Screen {
    stdout: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Screen {
    fn new(stdout: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Screen { stdout }
    }

    fn print_input(self, input: Input) {
        match input {
            Input::Text(text) => {
                println!("{}", &text);
            }
            Input::None => {
                println!("None");
            } 
            Input::Exit => {
                println!("Exit");
            }
        }
    }

    fn handle_input(self, prompt: Option<String>) -> Result<Input, InputError> {
        match prompt {
            Some(_) => {
                let input = get_input()?;
                // do something with prompt

                Ok(input)
            }
            None => {
                Ok(Input::None)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn get_input() -> Result<Input, InputError> {
    let input = "Text".to_owned();

    Ok(Input::Text(input))
}

fn main() {
    let screen = Screen::new(Vec::new());
    let prompt = Some("Prompt".to_string());
    let input = screen.handle_input(prompt);

    screen.print_input(input.unwrap());
}
```

As you can see, there's a move problem in `main()`:

```
60 |     let screen = Screen::new(Vec::new());
   |         ------ move occurs because `screen` has type `Screen`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
61 |     let prompt = Some("Prompt".to_string());
62 |     let input = screen.handle_input(prompt);
   |                        -------------------- `screen` moved due to this method call
63 |
64 |     screen.handle_input_result(input.unwrap());
   |     ^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
note: `Screen::handle_input` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `screen`
  --> src/main.rs:24:21
   |
24 |     fn handle_input(self, prompt: Option<String>) -> Result<Input, InputError> {
   |     

            ^^^^
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Don't take `self` by value in your methods but by reference. Replace `self` in your methods with `&self`. [Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d08152cb3d57242a94f775c14e4a935)

Comment: @JonasFassbender Oh, it works. In the original code, `self` has to be borrowed as mutable, so `&mut` works. Maybe post an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between self and its variants in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71990249/whats-the-difference-between-self-and-its-variants-in-rust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `self` to your methods by value, thus moving your `Screen` instance. Your methods don't require ownership over `self`, so you can just pass it by reference instead (`&self`), fixing your ownership error:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Input {
    Text(String),
    None,
    Exit,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum InputError {
    NotUTF8(Vec<u8>),
    EmptyString,
    IoError(std::io::Error),
}

struct Screen {
    stdout: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Screen {
    fn new(stdout: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        Screen { stdout }
    }

    fn print_input(&self, input: Input) {
        match input {
            Input::Text(text) => {
                println!("{}", &text);
            }
            Input::None => {
                println!("None");
            } 
            Input::Exit => {
                println!("Exit");
            }
        }
    }

    fn handle_input(&self, prompt: Option<String>) -> Result<Input, InputError> {
        match prompt {
            Some(_) => {
                let input = get_input()?;
                // do something with prompt

                Ok(input)
            }
            None => {
                Ok(Input::None)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn get_input() -> Result<Input, InputError> {
    let input = "Text".to_owned();

    Ok(Input::Text(input))
}

fn main() {
    let screen = Screen::new(Vec::new());
    let prompt = Some("Prompt".to_string());
    let input = screen.handle_input(prompt);

    screen.print_input(input.unwrap());
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d08152cb3d57242a94f775c14e4a935)